# Why is my Youtube video not showing on iFrame with Next.js and UIkit?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, next.js, uikit

I have place an iFrame tag in my Next.js component.
On my website I can see the frame but it says "Youtube does not authorize this connection".
What is wrong ?

Here is my code:

```
            <iframe 
                src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8gmARGvPlI" 
                width="1920" 
                height="1080" 
                frameBorder="0" 
                allowFullScreen 
                uk-responsive 
                uk-video="automute: true">
            </iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to play youtube videos in an iframe you need to do it using their APIs. You can learn more about how to do that here - https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

If you simply want to embed the video with no external control over the video you can simply embed it. More about embedding here - https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: It was very useful thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you get the video Id by using youtube api

```
<iframe
          id="ytplayer"
          className={}
          type="text/html"
          width="100%"
          height="360"
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?autoplay=0&origin=http://example.com&controls=0&rel=1`}
          frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
```