# Why when I use an Iframe to embed a youtube video I get GET https://www.youtube.com/img/meh7.png 404?

Tags: iframe, next.js, youtube

I am using iframe to embed youtube videos on my nextjs website. But I get an error in the browser console:

> GET https://www.youtube.com/img/meh7.png 404 index.js:1962

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () https://www.youtube.com/img/meh7.png:1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opc1L.png)

The iframe that youtube itself throws:

```
                  <iframe
                    width="500"
                    height="281"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E7wJTI-1dvQ"
                    title="YouTube video player"
                    frameBorder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowFullScreen
                  />
```

I'm not quite sure what it is. I think it could be the thumbnails, although I'm not sure, let alone have any idea of ​​the solution.

The video plays fine. It does not have any problem except for the error that the browser console throws

Why does this error come out? How do I solve this error?

I have obtained the iframe from youtube itself, but the error persists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Youtube video not showing on iFrame with Next.js and UIkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316753/why-is-my-youtube-video-not-showing-on-iframe-with-next-js-and-uikit)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I'm not looking to control playback with js: "The IFrame Player API allows you to embed a YouTube video player into a website and control the player with JavaScript."

I just want to "embed the video without external control over the video" which is what I did and it works great except for the error I get in the chrome console.

I request, please, that the question be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the youtube cookie service. You try to log in but you can't. I didn't find a way to disable it directly in the Iframe. But if I use the **react-lite-youtube-embed** package and set the `noCookie={true}` property to it to disable cookies the error goes away:

```
              <LiteYouTubeEmbed
                id="E7wJTI-1dvQ"
                title="What’s new in Material Design for the web (Chrome Dev Summit 2019)"
                noCookie={true}
              />
```

For more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lite-youtube-embed